# c# Query Builder "internal error invalid pane configuration"

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to build query using Query Builder it works fine but 
I got an error when I try to bind parameter to sql statement.
the error say "internal error invalid pane configuration"

I use ODP.NET and oracle as DBMS

```
SELECT        TRAINING.M_ITEMS.ITEM_NAME, TRAINING.M_ORDER_DETAILS.ITEM_QTY
FROM            TRAINING.M_ITEMS INNER JOIN
                         TRAINING.M_ORDER_DETAILS ON TRAINING.M_ITEMS.ITEM_ID = TRAINING.M_ORDER_DETAILS.ITEM_ID AND TRAINING.M_ORDER_DETAILS.ORDER_ID = :par
```

Comment: Please show more of the code as well as the complete stacktrace / error message

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am getting same error!